# Как накатить diff файл в Git

Tags: git

У меня есть diff файл, который я сделал в проекте. Я счекаутил репозиторий еще раз и хочу накатить на него этот diff-файл. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь командой [**git-apply**(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) вот так.

```
git apply ваш_файл_разницы.diff
```